# How we should use the "How to debug a bash script?" canonical question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate, canonical-questions

When I asked this question my purpose was two fold:

1. That people can self-help themselves into debugging their own scripts and discover what is wrong without asking us.
2. That it serves as a lighting rod to all "How I debug this script?" questions.

Now, we had [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/162247/41104) in which the OP seems to have two issues:

- How he can discover what's wrong
- Identify and fix whatever is wrong

For the first reason, I voted to close. It's a good behavior? Should we determine what kind of questions this can be a duplicated target for?